# javascript char code to WIN32 Virtual-Key Code

Tags: javascript, keyboard, virtual-keyboard, fromcharcode

How to convert in javascript char code to WIN32 Virtual-Key Code? I mean "q" allways has 81 code, even if i will press it in russian keyboard for example.
In wpf I can use this code, but I need something simular in javascript

```
keyCodeValue = System.Windows.Input.KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key)
```

Comment: Hi, probably late to the party, but, did you resolve this?